# error :n=int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N/A'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

Code runs fine in jupyter notebook but gives error in hacker rank

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,99):
    n= n+1
    if (n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0):
        print('FizzBuzz')
    elif (n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 != 0):
        print('Fizz')
    elif (n % 3 != 0 and n % 5 == 0):
        print('Buzz')
    else:
        print(n)
```

Comment: check thier test cases and code

Comment: Please format your question correctly and post the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that is the problem - `n = int(input())`

Maybe, hacker rank does not support `input` construction. Try to replace it for random value.

Comment: it works well when i am giving it some value , but should've worked with above code too

Comment: In that case, you can address your question to hacker rank, because it related to their restriction, but not with python.